# Bounce Email Management Issue 'IsEmailBounced' is not populated on Contact while Email Bounced

Tags: sales-cloud

I have enabled the bounce Management in the Sandbox. Email is bounced but fields not updated on Contact. See the Bounce Management settings in the screenshot. Is there any Security issue? I have enabled the Einstein Activity Capture in the sandbox. Does it affects any permission for email Activity? Can anyone tell how much time it needs to mark as true for 'isBouncedEmail' field? Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: What does it show when you query run SOQL on your contact record `SELECT EmailBouncedDate,EmailBouncedReason,Id,IsEmailBounced,Name FROM Contact WHERE Id = '0039000000vTiKN' ` Does it return true for IsEmailBounced field?

Comment: Yes IsEmailBounced field is not updated. I contacted with salesforce support and they asked There is Einstein Activity Capture is enabled, that is creating issue for Bounce Management.